# How to use Induino R3 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: serial, ubuntu

I have just got [Induino R3](http://www.induino.com/). I have installed Arduino on my Ubuntu. I tried blink example but it shows error `serial port COM1 not found`

I think i need to select proper option from *serial port*. But i can't click on it!

P.S. I am completely new to Arduino

Comment: is your user in the `dialout` group?

Comment: @BrettAM Yes it is i did it from http://askubuntu.com/a/146523/283650

Comment: does `/dev/ttyACM#` appear in your filesystem when the arduino is plugged in?

Comment: @BrettAM It is working now. I don't know how but as soon i upgraded Ubuntu from 14.04 to 14.10 is started working!! BTW thanks for help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure of the specific differences between your board and a normal Arduino[clone], but I've never seen serial devices referenced in Ubuntu via COM# labels(Granted I've only used or needed to use serial type devices in the last year, so I could be a bit under experienced).

Anyhow, usually I find serial devices available at /dev/ttyXXX. On my Lubuntu 14.04 installs, my USB connected Arduinos all show up as /dev/ttyACM#. I have an FTDI programmer I usually use on wifi routers which generally shows up as /dev/tty#.

Rule of thumb in Linux, everything is a file somewhere.

Comment: I did not get how to fix it from this answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance, download the Windows version of the Arduino IDE and install it under Wine? Then I would expect it to seek a COM# serial port. In which case you will have to create a symbolic link from the relevant /dev/ttyUSBx to COMx for your Arduino IDE to work.

The right way is to download the Arduino for Linux tar.gz file and extract it to a path of your choice in your Home folder.

Comment: I upgraded Ubuntu version 14.04 to 15.04 and now it is working fine!